# How to select rows be create after 1 hour?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to select rows be create after 1 hour?
now I'm select all rows and use momentjs to compare now, how to use single postgresql query do it?

id | create_date
1  | 2016-09-22 00:36:41
2  | 2016-09-21 00:36:41
3  | 2016-09-22 01:36:41

if now is `2016-09-22 01:37:41` select `1, 2`

```
 SELECT * 
  FROM signup_pending 
  ??// WHERE create_date - '1 hour'::INTERVAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like that:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM signup_pending 
 WHERE now() < create_date + '1 hour'::INTERVAL
```

Comment: thanks for reply I try this but it will get row 3 ??

Comment: Well, that depends on the value of `now()` which changes as time passes by.

Comment: thanks! I change `WHERE NOW() > (create_date + '1 hour'::INTERVAL)`` select row 1,2` and  `WHERE NOW() < (create_date + '1 hour'::INTERVAL)`;` select row 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select create_date from signup_pending where create_date < DATEADD(hour, -1, getdate())
```